How to actively engage with philosophical texts?
As a philosophy enthusiast, I've been reading various texts and have recently dived into classics like Kant's Critique of Pure Reason and Hegel's Phenomenology of Spirit. While I enjoy reading and understanding these texts, I'm looking for ways to actively engage with them. How can I do this without resorting to blind criticism of every sentence? What specific types of exercises or practices can help me develop my own philosophical thoughts while understanding the great thinkers?  I’m looking for more specific answers than vague statements about critical thinking. I want to move beyond passive consumption and participate in the philosophical conversation.
Thanks in advance.

I use my conversational chatbots to interactively engage with philosophical works.

One very useful technique is to discuss the text with someone else interested in philosophy.

@MichalRyszardWojcik yes! It’s fun to debate ChatGPT

@Annika Do you have some conversations to share via a link?

Like you, I am an avid, albeit very amateur, philosophy enthusiast.
Many people think that philosophy is very removed from everyday concerns, but I think quite the opposite, it's  just that like any profession, philosophers have gone very very deep and have their own jargon.
Here are the things that go through my mind as I read philosophy:

How could I apply this perspective to a current topic in the news?
What would [topic A] have to say about [topic B] (e.g., how would you apply the concepts in CoPR to Hegel's ideas?)
(If there are proofs/derivations) Try to derive them yourself or extend them.
Are there interesting ways to combine what you've read?
Who (if anyone) has "taken the torch" from the person you are reading? What are they doing to further the topic?

All of this will help you engage deeper and also see philosophy as a living, active field.

Taking your point about philosophers have their own jargon, how would you explain it to a layman, without using said jargon?  :)

@Stewart  can you clarify what “it” refers to?

The philosophy in question, whichever that is. For example, how would you explain Hegel's Phenomenology to a layman. I think that's a great way to actively engage with a work of philosophy. Like you, I agree that philosophy is not (should not be) removed from everyday concerns. So a corollary of that is, how do you make it practical and usable someone who does not know the jargon?

@Stewart -- ah, yes!! +1 ... how would you explain or teach it to someone else?

I like to ask the following questions:

What clear and definite philosophical claims does this text make?
Are these claims new or have I heard them before?
Are the arguments for these claims clear and convincing?
Having considered the arguments, do I judge that these claims are true?

These questions are helpful to stay focused on what matters most: thinking about philosophy. The text has helped you do that if you come away from it with new philosophical beliefs you didn't have before, or stronger arguments for or against some proposition than you had before.
This stands in contrast to, say, entertaining you, making you feel a personal connection with the author, or giving you some gestalt mood. Although perhaps desirable in their own way, these things aren't going to help you think better. Philosophy is about the ideas.
Ultimately your goal is to work out and justify your own personal system of philosophical beliefs. Which of the arguments you read make sense to you? Which don't? For any given topic you can find reputable philosophers on both sides of it, so in the end you really have to make up your own mind. Sitting back and meditating on the topic helps. I also like to go for walks and think. There's no trusting in authority, in philosophy.

You could use a well-studied method of actively engaging with content: visible thinking. I will explain what Visible Thinking Routines are by using one:
See-Think-Wonder:

I see that you're interested in actively engaging with philosophical texts. You mention you want exercises or practices to help you develop your thought and also understand great thinkers.
I think using Visible Thinking Routines will help you, because they serve as small, portable routines that, while apparently simple, improve understanding. They were developed by Harvard's Project Zero as a way of explaining why some teachers were able to engage their students better and why some students had dispositions that lead them to consistently understand content better. These thinking routines/dispositions can be learned.
I wonder if you will learn and apply the visible thinking routines.

I often read whatever I'm learning (e.g. a text on social sciences) and then do a thinking routine. Then I go back to the text, and then another thinking routine, and so on. It helps to do the routines without looking at the base text, because then you're also engaging your active recall, which helps for understanding.
As to your concern of "blind criticism of every sentence", visible thinking routines can help in some ways:

They can be used in different scales: a single sentence, a whole book, a whole body of work from an author, etc..
I would argue visible thinking routines help you develop your own criteria. These criteria may not coincide with that of other communities of knowers (such as contemporary philosophers in university departments), but your intuition can help you know what criticism is 'blind' and which is worthwhile for you think about (visibly or otherwise).
If you do wish to engage with communities of knowers, visible thinking can help with formative evaluation or by contrasting what you're thinking with what others are saying.

Some resources:

Making Thinking Visible by Ron Ritchhart, Mark Church, and Karin Morrison. This book gives you the theoretical basis for thinking routines and suggestions on how to learn them and use them.

The understanding map. It's helpful to choose what kind of thinking to do in a particular moment.



Bring some friends
When engaging with very theory-laden texts about a philosophical problems, I try to bring with me a small collection of concrete example situations or questions to which the theory at hand is applicable to. These examples serve as "measuring rods" that help me evaluate which conclusions or decisions they would me lead to.
That makes it easier to engage my episodic thinking and memorizing modes with the new theory, allowing to better integrate the results with one's everyday thinking.
Some examples?

Ethical theories: medical triage, animal experiments/testing
Epistemology: any questions from Skeptics.SE
Political theories: questions of individual rights w.r.t. the common good. (Wealth distribution, private property)
Philosophy of mind: when is an AI conscious? Am I conscious? "What is free will?" and possibly: "Do I have free will?" or "Does anybody have free will?"


To actively engage with philosophical texts, one can choose a delimited text - well-known in the history of philosophy - and pose to the text the following questions:

Which are its 5-10 key terms?
Is the meaning of each term clear? Did the author define the term? How would you define it in your own words?

Is there a philosophical problem which the text wants to solve?
Does the text state this problem explicitly? Is the problem interesting for you? Have you already considered this issue yourself?

Which ideas and arguments does the text present to solve the problem?
How does the text use the key terms to elaborate the solution?

How does the solution look like?
Can you formulate the solution in your own words?

Which presuppositions does the solution make?
Do you agree with these assumptions?


In the beginning, one can practice this method with some short classical texts, e.g., Plato’s anamnesis doctrine, Aristotle’s classification of the 4-fold cause, the first Question from Summa Theologiae of Thomas Aquinas, Popper’s solution of Hume’s problem.
Later one can proceed to complete works like Kant’s Critique of Pure Reason, Thus Spoke Zarathustra by Nietzsche, Heidegger’s Being and Time.
Added: I see that that my proposal is similar to the proposal of @causative.
